# Multibinding to two different DataContexts in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext, multibinding

In a `MultiBinding` if the DataContext is set as `VM1` and `C` is a property of that, is it possible to do the second binding to a different DataContext like `VM2` and bind it to `D` property in `VM2`?

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnitConverter}">
        <Binding Path="C"/>
        <Binding Path="D"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Answer (score 8):

Quick answer, yes! If you for example have a Grid with `Datacontext` VM2, and inside this you have a Stackpanel with `Datacontext` VM1. You can now use `RelativeSource` to get the correct `Datacontext` by traveling up the visual tree.
I'm not on my windows laptop atm but it should look something like this..

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnitConverter}">
    <Binding Path="DataContext.D" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}"/>
    <Binding Path="C"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

I hope this helped

This question may also be of help: [How to get a parent value in multibinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714134/how-to-get-a-parent-value-in-multibinding)

Comment: But what if the second data context is not defined in the visual tree?

Comment: You need to have some kind of reference to it. Maybe a property in the first Datacontext that leads to the second view model for example. Otherwise, as far as I know it is not possible unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry. The exact answer is **Impossible**.
What you're saying is impossible since the datacontext is set to some view model say `VM1` and the template will be looking for some property inside that very data context only.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnitConverter}">
        <Binding Path="C"/>
        <Binding Path="D"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

In above code, C and D should be inside the same datacontext. Or else you need to create a new viewmodel that contains properties of sub view models, so that the sub viewmodel properties could be accessed like below :

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnitConverter}">
        <Binding Path="VM1.C"/>
        <Binding Path="VM2.D"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

where VM1 and VM2 are view model instances created as properties in the datacontext view model.